# How to use Numeral.js library in angular2/ionic 2 typescript app?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-pipe, numeral.js

I have been successful using Numeral.js library in my angularJs(1.x) applications to format my numbers in different formats. This is how I use angular1 filters:

filter.js

```
.filter('numeral', function () {
  return function (count) {
    var numericalFormat = numeral(count).format('0.0a');
    return numericalFormat;
  };
})
```

For that I followed the official [docs of Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)
and installed using npm. I also give reference to nodemodules in index.html.

In the Browser

```
<script src="node_modules/numeral/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

but it shows

> ERROR ReferenceError: numeral is not defined
>       at NumeralFilter.transform

Initially I tried with using CDN reference, it works as I expected in the browser. But when I installed the app on real device I am getting an error "numeral is not defined".

pipe

```
import {Pipe,PipeTransform,Injectable} from "@angular/core"
@Pipe({
name:'numeralPipe'
})
@Injectable()
export class NumeralPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(count:any):any{ //eg: in count has value something like 52456.0
       var numericalFormat = numeral(count).format('0.0a');//error here
    return numericalFormat; // i have to format it like 52,5k
  }; 
}
```

Is there any type script library for formatting and manipulating numbers, or is there any way to do this in angular2?

Comment: try adding `declare var numeral:any` after  `import {Pipe,PipeTransform,Injectable} from "@angular/core"`

Comment: Added as answer. you can accept & Upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

`declare var numeral:any`

after

```
import {Pipe,PipeTransform,Injectable} from "@angular/core".
```

Comment: hey Ghiya! i have been successful in browser via cdn but when i build it app getting error on the device. so i tried to install it via npm again i am getting same error in the browser also. i have updated my question.

Comment: have u ensured that the js is there in dist folder, post your file strucure. you are using angular cli ?

Comment: actually it is an ionic-2 app.

Comment: u using CDN ? or u using JS from lib ? am postive that JS Is not loaded

Comment: i had installed numeral.js via npm. and gave reference in index.html as <script src="node_modules/numeral/numeral.min.js"></script>

Comment: i have removed cdn

Comment: try 1 thing for me, use CDN for JS Inclusion in index.html & let me know it works or not ?

Comment: If that works, you will have to place any JS In www folder, then and only then it will be included in the build, the build wont include your node_modules, hence it gives error

Comment: as i mentioned above i tried with using CDN first it works as i expected in the browser . but when i installed the app on real device i am getting error. numeral is not defined

Comment: because in build scripts from node_modules are not loaded.! you need to take that JS out & keep it in www folder.

Comment: how can i do that? any suggestion would be Great

Comment: i dont know the best way, but from node modules, copy the JS in to www folder & change path accordingly in index.html. Anything inside www will be included in build.

Answer (score 9):

add package to Node Modules folder with

```
yarn add numeral
```

or

```
npm install numeral
```

then import into Typescript file

`import * as numeral from 'numeral';`